# Is there anything similar to WPF and MVVM in Java world?

Tags: java, .net, wpf, mvvm

Is there anything similar to WPF and MVVM in Java world?

Comment: +1 Taking a Java class to extend my knowledge currently. Final project only requires Swing, I'm an MVVM/WPF man myself. Would rather go far and above the requirements to learn some useful Java. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you seen [eFace](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=47205) ?

> eFace  is a XAML/WPF solution in Java.
>   The first release is available for
>   download now :
>   http://www.soyatec.com/eface/installation/.

JavaFX provides some of the capabilities of WPF. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285147/what-is-javas-answer-to-wpf) for more details.

Comment: Does either one provide binding via the use of Data Contexts?

Answer (score 2):

Start from version 6, ZK provide a series of powerful features of meta programming support, such as  CSS Selector in Java and MVVM in Java.

You can take a look at this link:

http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/November/Hello_ZK_MVVM
[http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/JanuaryEnvisage_ZK_6:_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2011/JanuaryEnvisage_ZK_6%3a_An_Annotation_Based_Composer_For_MVC)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the WCS-MVC pattern of Jrebirth Application Framework.

This pattern was designe after having worked with PureMVC and Mircrosoft MVVM.
Note that the Model View ViewModel pattern silently add a (ViewController with the .xaml.cs file....), that will add a lot of confusion

**WCS-MVC means :**

- Wave => manage events between components
- Command => manage atomic or multi actions in separate thread (JAT, JIT, JTP)
- Service => manage long action with progree notifications
- Model => manage business logic for view
- View => define the ui tree
- Controller => listen user interaction

JRebirth offers :

- thread management
- lower memory footprint
- good Separation of Concern
- an internal notification engine to let each component communicate with others in an asynchronous way.