# What is Javas answer to Winforms / WPF / Silverlight in 2011

Tags: java, wpf, winforms, silverlight

We are doing an evaluation of what to use for client technology, I was wondering what Java has to offer.

I know that this is a close duplicate to this question:

[What is Java's answer to WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285147/what-is-javas-answer-to-wpf)

But the answer in the above question is over 2 years old, so the answer today could be different.

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same. Only the version number has increased for WPF and soon will for java. Just incremental changes if you asked me, nothing revolutionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [JavaFX](http://javafx.com/) still lives. You can check [Eclipse Rich Ajax Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/rap/downloads/) too. I think this is suitaible answer to Silverlight.

Answer (score 4):

This 2011 Java wil lunch [JavaFX 2.0](http://javafx.com/roadmap/), you will use the [JavaFX API's with core Java language](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/hello_javafx_2_back_to) instead of the JavaFX Script in 1.x versions.

Answer (score 3):

I concur with the others here that JavaFX *was* probably intended to be Sun's answer to WPF and Silverlight, but it's never quite reached the standard that Microsoft's technologies have.

Another Java alternative to Silverlight is [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/) and [Spring BlazeDS](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) which use a Java application server as the backend, and Adobe Flash as the client (using Flex). I've never used it, but the combination looks pretty similar to using Silverlight.

Answer (score 3):

JavaFX is in full swing and Oracle has already made early access release available. More answers can be found [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/javaspotlight/resource/episode-016.html), but surely a competitor is in the making that will give its counterpart a tough time soon