# Java GUI framework similar to .NET

Tags: java, .net, wpf, user-interface

Is there a similar plugin/framework for GUI creation in Java as it exists in .NET? I am talking about the new XAML/WPF world, with a neat, interactive content panes, which you can pretty much arrange using mouse rather than coding the styles and visual properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Java's answer to WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285147/what-is-javas-answer-to-wpf)

Comment: *"Is there a similar plugin/framework for GUI creation in Java as it exists in .NET?"*  Since Java aims to support multiple PLAfs and platforms, the 'drop it wherever you like' approach does not really work.  Don't get me wrong, it might be possible to offer a D-n-D Java GUI maker, but the user would need to understand the layouts and how to use them before it would be possible to produce a sensible, workable GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the plugin for eclipse and the internal plugin of Netbeans with Swing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analog to WPF, there are Swing GUI, JavaFX, but these frameworks are far to WPF form .NET, just for my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at JavaFX and the [Scene Builder for JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), it is Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

this [JavaFx](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Controls) this is a internal link for viewing GUI part