# Does Java have any framework similar to WPF( as it has capability of using shaders)

Tags: c#, java, wpf

I have been wondering like most of the desktop application which has to deal with the simulation and design stuff has been designed in WPF, So, I wanted to know is there anything similar to WPF in java and which has each & every capability of WPF

" This question may be having similar variants and all question ends up with the answer JavaFX and combination of couple of frameworks".
as better explained at this question [What is Java's answer to WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285147/what-is-javas-answer-to-wpf)

**So, does java have a single piece of framework which has got each and every capability of WPF Including hardware based rendering(GPGPU programming) and even call pixel shader, vertex shader and geometry shader.**